# How do I find the resolution of the screen my form is currently sitting in

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I know I can find the screen resolution of the Primary screen easily, but I want to find the resolution of the screen that my form is currently sitting in (this is not the same on my setup I have three screens with two different resolutions)

I appreciate that the form could span more than one screen so I would be happy with finding the screen that contains the most area of the form/the top left corner

Is there a simple way to do this?

I can enumerate the screens, but then working out where my form is sitting within this is tricky:

```
    For Each scr As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
        If Me.Left > scr.WorkingArea.Left AndAlso Me.Left < (scr.WorkingArea.Left + scr.WorkingArea.Width) Then 'etc

        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can enumerate the screens, but then working out where my form is
>   sitting within this is tricky

.Net provides built-in method for this

Take a look at [Screen.FromControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx)

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen A Screen for the display that
>   contains the largest region of the specified control. In multiple
>   display environments where no display contains the control, the
>   display closest to the specified control is returned.